# How to get project path in Sonarqube Javascript Extension

Tags: javascript, java, sonarqube

I am writing a custom rules plugin for the SonarQube Javascript Plugin.
Now I want to disable my check in specific directories by the rule. (It should not be checked in the bin path for example)

Now my question: how can I get the path of the file that is checked relative to the project path. Or another Solution would be: How to get the project path?

My code is:

```
@Override
public void visitNode(Tree tree) {
    CallExpressionTree callExpression = (CallExpressionTree) tree;

    if (callExpression.callee().is(Kind.DOT_MEMBER_EXPRESSION)) {
        DotMemberExpressionTree callee = (DotMemberExpressionTree) callExpression.callee();

        // get the file that is checked
        File toTestedFile = getContext().getFile();

        //how to get the project path here to get the relative path???

        if (isCalleeConsoleLogging(callee)) {
            addLineIssue(tree, MESSAGE);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the platform exclusions mechanism is for. If I were you, I wouldn't try to put such exclusions into a rule implementation. Instead, just write a blanket/generic rule implementation and set [Issue exclusions](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreIssues) at the global level to ignore the directories you want to leave out.